# How to get different windows in root window tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello guys im trying to make a point of sale software using tkinter. as in the sample picture i want to create one root window but display different things when any menu button is clicked, now i dont want to create separate windows when for example settings button is clicked, i want the settings to display in the same root window, should i use a frame for that or what widget should i use? im new to this any help would be appreciated :)))

[image]

Comment: You could use multiple `tk.Frame`, and use `tk.raise` when necessary.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA ok ill try that thanks

Answer (score 0):

The please see the following answer on how this can be done:
[Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028)

On a side note i have also created a gist on how switching between frames can be acheived as well as the inclusion of a login/register page. You can copy and paste the code in a text editor to demo it for yourself. (please bare in mind that it very loosely follows a architecture pattern).
https://gist.github.com/RamonWill/0422b061464097a7a0162f33e4c13a2e
Code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk



# You can also use a pandas dataframe for pokemon_info.
# you can convert the dataframe using df.to_numpy.tolist()
pokemon_info = [['Bulbasaur', 'Grass', '318'], ['Ivysaur', 'Grass', '405'], ['Venusaur', 'Grass', '525'], ['Charmander', 'Fire', '309'], ['Charmeleon', 'Fire', '405'], ['Charizard', 'Fire', '534'], ['Squirtle', 'Water', '314'], ['Wartortle', 'Water', '405'], ['Blastoise', 'Water', '530'], ['Caterpie', 'Bug', '195'], ['Metapod', 'Bug', '205'], ['Butterfree', 'Bug', '395'], ['Weedle', 'Bug', '195'], ['Kakuna', 'Bug', '205'], ['Beedrill', 'Bug', '395'], ['Pidgey', 'Normal', '251'], ['Pidgeotto', 'Normal', '349'], ['Pidgeot', 'Normal', '479'], ['Rattata', 'Normal', '253'], ['Raticate', 'Normal', '413'], ['Spearow', 'Normal', '262'], ['Fearow', 'Normal', '442'], ['Ekans', 'Poison', '288'], ['Arbok', 'Poison', '448'], ['Pikachu', 'Electric', '320'], ['Raichu', 'Electric', '485'], ['Sandshrew', 'Ground', '300'], ['Sandslash', 'Ground', '450'], ['Nidoran?', 'Poison', '275'], ['Nidorina', 'Poison', '365'], ['Nidoqueen', 'Poison', '505'], ['Nidoran?', 'Poison', '273'], ['Nidorino', 'Poison', '365'], ['Nidoking', 'Poison', '505'], ['Clefairy', 'Fairy', '323'], ['Clefable', 'Fairy', '483'], ['Vulpix', 'Fire', '299'], ['Ninetales', 'Fire', '505'], ['Jigglypuff', 'Normal', '270'], ['Wigglytuff', 'Normal', '435'], ['Zubat', 'Poison', '245'], ['Golbat', 'Poison', '455'], ['Oddish', 'Grass', '320'], ['Gloom', 'Grass', '395'], ['Vileplume', 'Grass', '490'], ['Paras', 'Bug', '285'], ['Parasect', 'Bug', '405'], ['Venonat', 'Bug', '305'], ['Venomoth', 'Bug', '450'], ['Diglett', 'Ground', '265'], ['Dugtrio', 'Ground', '425'], ['Meowth', 'Normal', '290'], ['Persian', 'Normal', '440'], ['Psyduck', 'Water', '320'], ['Golduck', 'Water', '500'], ['Mankey', 'Fighting', '305'], ['Primeape', 'Fighting', '455'], ['Growlithe', 'Fire', '350'], ['Arcanine', 'Fire', '555'], ['Poliwag', 'Water', '300'], ['Poliwhirl', 'Water', '385'], ['Poliwrath', 'Water', '510'], ['Abra', 'Psychic', '310'], ['Kadabra', 'Psychic', '400'], ['Alakazam', 'Psychic', '500'], ['Machop', 'Fighting', '305'], ['Machoke', 'Fighting', '405'], ['Machamp', 'Fighting', '505'], ['Bellsprout', 'Grass', '300'], ['Weepinbell', 'Grass', '390'], ['Victreebel', 'Grass', '490'], ['Tentacool', 'Water', '335'], ['Tentacruel', 'Water', '515'], ['Geodude', 'Rock', '300'], ['Graveler', 'Rock', '390'], ['Golem', 'Rock', '495'], ['Ponyta', 'Fire', '410'], ['Rapidash', 'Fire', '500'], ['Slowpoke', 'Water', '315'], ['Slowbro', 'Water', '490'], ['Magnemite', 'Electric', '325'], ['Magneton', 'Electric', '465'], ["Farfetch'd", 'Normal', '377'], ['Doduo', 'Normal', '310'], ['Dodrio', 'Normal', '470'], ['Seel', 'Water', '325'], ['Dewgong', 'Water', '475'], ['Grimer', 'Poison', '325'], ['Muk', 'Poison', '500'], ['Shellder', 'Water', '305'], ['Cloyster', 'Water', '525'], ['Gastly', 'Ghost', '310'], ['Haunter', 'Ghost', '405'], ['Gengar', 'Ghost', '500'], ['Onix', 'Rock', '385'], ['Drowzee', 'Psychic', '328'], ['Hypno', 'Psychic', '483'], ['Krabby', 'Water', '325'], ['Kingler', 'Water', '475'], ['Voltorb', 'Electric', '330'], ['Electrode', 'Electric', '490'], ['Exeggcute', 'Grass', '325'], ['Exeggutor', 'Grass', '530'], ['Cubone', 'Ground', '320'], ['Marowak', 'Ground', '425'], ['Hitmonlee', 'Fighting', '455'], ['Hitmonchan', 'Fighting', '455'], ['Lickitung', 'Normal', '385'], ['Koffing', 'Poison', '340'], ['Weezing', 'Poison', '490'], ['Rhyhorn', 'Ground', '345'], ['Rhydon', 'Ground', '485'], ['Chansey', 'Normal', '450'], ['Tangela', 'Grass', '435'], ['Kangaskhan', 'Normal', '490'], ['Horsea', 'Water', '295'], ['Seadra', 'Water', '440'], ['Goldeen', 'Water', '320'], ['Seaking', 'Water', '450'], ['Staryu', 'Water', '340'], ['Starmie', 'Water', '520'], ['Scyther', 'Bug', '500'], ['Jynx', 'Ice', '455'], ['Electabuzz', 'Electric', '490'], ['Magmar', 'Fire', '495'], ['Pinsir', 'Bug', '500'], ['Tauros', 'Normal', '490'], ['Magikarp', 'Water', '200'], ['Gyarados', 'Water', '540'], ['Lapras', 'Water', '535'], ['Ditto', 'Normal', '288'], ['Eevee', 'Normal', '325'], ['Vaporeon', 'Water', '525'], ['Jolteon', 'Electric', '525'], ['Flareon', 'Fire', '525'], ['Porygon', 'Normal', '395'], ['Omanyte', 'Rock', '355'], ['Omastar', 'Rock', '495'], ['Kabuto', 'Rock', '355'], ['Kabutops', 'Rock', '495'], ['Aerodactyl', 'Rock', '515'], ['Snorlax', 'Normal', '540'], ['Articuno', 'Ice', '580'], ['Zapdos', 'Electric', '580'], ['Moltres', 'Fire', '580'], ['Dratini', 'Dragon', '300'], ['Dragonair', 'Dragon', '420'], ['Dragonite', 'Dragon', '600'], ['Mewtwo', 'Psychic', '680'], ['Mew', 'Psychic', '600']]


frame_styles = {"relief": "groove",
                "bd": 3, "bg": "#BEB2A7",
                "fg": "#073bb3", "font": ("Arial", 9, "bold")}


class LoginPage(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#708090", height=431, width=626)  # this is the background
        main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")

        self.geometry("626x431")  # Sets window size to 626w x 431h pixels
        self.resizable(0, 0)  # This prevents any resizing of the screen
        title_styles = {"font": ("Trebuchet MS Bold", 16), "background": "blue"}

        text_styles = {"font": ("Verdana", 14),
                       "background": "blue",
                       "foreground": "#E1FFFF"}

        frame_login = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg="blue", relief="groove", bd=2)  # this is the frame that holds all the login details and buttons
        frame_login.place(rely=0.30, relx=0.17, height=130, width=400)

        label_title = tk.Label(frame_login, title_styles, text="Login Page")
        label_title.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1)

        label_user = tk.Label(frame_login, text_styles, text="Username:")
        label_user.grid(row=1, column=0)

        label_pw = tk.Label(frame_login, text_styles, text="Password:")
        label_pw.grid(row=2, column=0)

        entry_user = ttk.Entry(frame_login, width=45, cursor="xterm")
        entry_user.grid(row=1, column=1)

        entry_pw = ttk.Entry(frame_login, width=45, cursor="xterm", show="*")
        entry_pw.grid(row=2, column=1)

        button = ttk.Button(frame_login, text="Login", command=lambda: getlogin())
        button.place(rely=0.70, relx=0.50)

        signup_btn = ttk.Button(frame_login, text="Register", command=lambda: get_signup())
        signup_btn.place(rely=0.70, relx=0.75)

        def get_signup():
            SignupPage()

        def getlogin():
            username = entry_user.get()
            password = entry_pw.get()
            # if your want to run the script as it is set validation = True
            validation = validate(username, password)
            if validation:
                tk.messagebox.showinfo("Login Successful",
                                       "Welcome {}".format(username))
                root.deiconify()
                top.destroy()
            else:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The Username or Password you have entered are incorrect ")

        def validate(username, password):
            # Checks the text file for a username/password combination.
            try:
                with open("credentials.txt", "r") as credentials:
                    for line in credentials:
                        line = line.split(",")
                        if line[1] == username and line[3] == password:
                            return True
                    return False
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("You need to Register first or amend Line 71 to     if True:")
                return False


class SignupPage(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#3F6BAA", height=150, width=250)
        # pack_propagate prevents the window resizing to match the widgets
        main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")

        self.geometry("250x150")
        self.resizable(0, 0)

        self.title("Registration")

        text_styles = {"font": ("Verdana", 10),
                       "background": "#3F6BAA",
                       "foreground": "#E1FFFF"}

        label_user = tk.Label(main_frame, text_styles, text="New Username:")
        label_user.grid(row=1, column=0)

        label_pw = tk.Label(main_frame, text_styles, text="New Password:")
        label_pw.grid(row=2, column=0)

        entry_user = ttk.Entry(main_frame, width=20, cursor="xterm")
        entry_user.grid(row=1, column=1)

        entry_pw = ttk.Entry(main_frame, width=20, cursor="xterm", show="*")
        entry_pw.grid(row=2, column=1)

        button = ttk.Button(main_frame, text="Create Account", command=lambda: signup())
        button.grid(row=4, column=1)

        def signup():
            # Creates a text file with the Username and password
            user = entry_user.get()
            pw = entry_pw.get()
            validation = validate_user(user)
            if not validation:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "That Username already exists")
            else:
                if len(pw) > 3:
                    credentials = open("credentials.txt", "a")
                    credentials.write(f"Username,{user},Password,{pw},\n")
                    credentials.close()
                    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Information", "Your account details have been stored.")
                    SignupPage.destroy(self)

                else:
                    tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "Your password needs to be longer than 3 values.")

        def validate_user(username):
            # Checks the text file for a username/password combination.
            try:
                with open("credentials.txt", "r") as credentials:
                    for line in credentials:
                        line = line.split(",")
                        if line[1] == username:
                            return False
                return True
            except FileNotFoundError:
                return True

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        menu_file = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="Menu1", menu=menu_file)
        menu_file.add_command(label="All Widgets", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(Some_Widgets))
        menu_file.add_separator()
        menu_file.add_command(label="Exit Application", command=lambda: parent.Quit_application())

        menu_orders = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="Menu2", menu=menu_orders)

        menu_pricing = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="Menu3", menu=menu_pricing)
        menu_pricing.add_command(label="Page One", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(PageOne))

        menu_operations = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="Menu4", menu=menu_operations)
        menu_operations.add_command(label="Page Two", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(PageTwo))
        menu_positions = tk.Menu(menu_operations, tearoff=0)
        menu_operations.add_cascade(label="Menu5", menu=menu_positions)
        menu_positions.add_command(label="Page Three", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(PageThree))
        menu_positions.add_command(label="Page Four", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(PageFour))

        menu_help = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="Menu6", menu=menu_help)
        menu_help.add_command(label="Open New Window", command=lambda: parent.OpenNewWindow())


class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#84CEEB", height=600, width=1024)
        main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # self.resizable(0, 0) prevents the app from being resized
        # self.geometry("1024x600") fixes the applications size
        self.frames = {}
        pages = (Some_Widgets, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour)
        for F in pages:
            frame = F(main_frame, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(Some_Widgets)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

    def show_frame(self, name):
        frame = self.frames[name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def OpenNewWindow(self):
        OpenNewWindow()

    def Quit_application(self):
        self.destroy()


class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#BEB2A7", height=600, width=1024)
        # self.main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        self.main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


class Some_Widgets(GUI):  # inherits from the GUI class
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        GUI.__init__(self, parent)

        frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, frame_styles, text="This is a LabelFrame containing a Treeview")
        frame1.place(rely=0.05, relx=0.02, height=400, width=400)

        frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, frame_styles, text="Some widgets")
        frame2.place(rely=0.05, relx=0.45, height=500, width=500)

        button1 = tk.Button(frame2, text="tk button", command=lambda: Refresh_data())
        button1.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(frame2, text="ttk button", command=lambda: Refresh_data())
        button2.pack()

        Var1 = tk.IntVar()
        Var2 = tk.IntVar()
        Cbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(frame2, text="tk CheckButton1", variable=Var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        Cbutton1.pack()
        Cbutton2 = tk.Checkbutton(frame2, text="tk CheckButton2", variable=Var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        Cbutton2.pack()

        Cbutton3 = ttk.Checkbutton(frame2, text="ttk CheckButton1", variable=Var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        Cbutton3.pack()
        Cbutton3 = ttk.Checkbutton(frame2, text="ttk CheckButton2", variable=Var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        Cbutton3.pack()

        Lbox1 = tk.Listbox(frame2, selectmode="multiple")
        Lbox1.insert(1, "This is a tk ListBox")
        Lbox1.insert(2, "Github")
        Lbox1.insert(3, "Python")
        Lbox1.insert(3, "StackOverflow")
        Lbox1.pack(side="left")

        Var3 = tk.IntVar()
        R1 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="tk Radiobutton1", variable=Var3, value=1)
        R1.pack()
        R2 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="tk Radiobutton2", variable=Var3, value=2)
        R2.pack()
        R3 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="tk Radiobutton3", variable=Var3, value=3)
        R3.pack()

        R4 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="ttk Radiobutton1", variable=Var3, value=1)
        R4.pack()
        R5 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="ttk Radiobutton2", variable=Var3, value=2)
        R5.pack()
        R6 = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="ttk Radiobutton3", variable=Var3, value=3)
        R6.pack()

        # This is a treeview.
        tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
        column_list_account = ["Name", "Type", "Base Stat Total"]
        tv1['columns'] = column_list_account
        tv1["show"] = "headings"  # removes empty column
        for column in column_list_account:
            tv1.heading(column, text=column)
            tv1.column(column, width=50)
        tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.995)
        treescroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame1)
        treescroll.configure(command=tv1.yview)
        tv1.configure(yscrollcommand=treescroll.set)
        treescroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        def Load_data():
            for row in pokemon_info:
                tv1.insert("", "end", values=row)

        def Refresh_data():
            # Deletes the data in the current treeview and reinserts it.
            tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())  # *=splat operator
            Load_data()

        Load_data()


class PageOne(GUI):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        GUI.__init__(self, parent)

        label1 = tk.Label(self.main_frame, font=("Verdana", 20), text="Page One")
        label1.pack(side="top")


class PageThree(GUI):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        GUI.__init__(self, parent)

        label1 = tk.Label(self.main_frame, font=("Verdana", 20), text="Page Three")
        label1.pack(side="top")


class PageFour(GUI):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        GUI.__init__(self, parent)

        label1 = tk.Label(self.main_frame, font=("Verdana", 20), text="Page Four")
        label1.pack(side="top")


class PageTwo(GUI):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        GUI.__init__(self, parent)

        label1 = tk.Label(self.main_frame, font=("Verdana", 20), text="Page Two")
        label1.pack(side="top")


class OpenNewWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.title("Here is the Title of the Window")
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.resizable(0, 0)

        frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(main_frame, text="This is a ttk LabelFrame")
        frame1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, font=("Verdana", 20), text="OpenNewWindow Page")
        label1.pack(side="top")


top = LoginPage()
top.title("Tkinter App Template - Login Page")
root = MyApp()
root.withdraw()
root.title("Tkinter App Template")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful. This is called a tab layout in Tkinter and you can create any tabs you want according to your requirement. Then add frames within tabs and so on...

You can achieve what you are looking for with this method. There is also another method, which is creating multiple frames within a for loop and when the user presses a button the frame changes according to the described function. But I recommend using a tab layout which is more efficient than using for loops for which the time complexity will be not efficient. I know this has been posted a year ago but maybe someone in future might find something helpful for their problem.

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Anything you like')
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Anything you like')
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

ttk.Label(tab1, text ="This is tab1").grid(column = 0, row = 0,padx= 30,pady = 30)  
ttk.Label(tab2,text ="This is tab2").grid(column = 0,row = 0,padx = 30,pady = 30)

root.mainloop()
```